# All windows entries return to grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, grub-efi

When trying to boot into windows 10 from grub on my Ubuntu 19.10/Windows 10 my system instead swiftly returns to grub as though I had just booted.

I have tried all of the following :

- running `sudo update-grub`
- running `sudo update-grub2`
- [following these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/217970/998318)
  [following the "boot repair" section of these instructions plus some extra options](https://askubuntu.com/a/921722/998318) ; [pastebin output]
- List item

(https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/75fnGjk5MD/)

**Possible causes**
Prior to my discovering this issue but after my last successful Windows boot (that I remember)

1. Updated to Ubuntu 19.10 from 19.04
2. Reactivated certain Windows features (system protection, hibernation, page files)
3. [Other steps detailed in comments on this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1187792/998318)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you boot into windows at all if you change your boot priorities so that Windows boot manager is again on top?

Comment: @darksky When Windows is set as default it trows an error along the lines of "`primary and secondary options failed to boot. Press any key to continue`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why this worked or if it will for others but I was able to fix my issue by using the `purge grub and reinstall` option in the boot repair program.